# Custom ordering in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a teachers model, which displays teachers list in view, but I want that head of the school will be always top in the view, their helpers next and teachers last.

How I could add a custom sorting trough a form?
Maybe there is any javascript plugin which could move or down teachers in the list?

Comment: How are the school director, the staff and teachers different from one another in the database or the model?

Comment: In form I have a profession text_area where administrator can write in what profession a person is working there, for example, mathematics teacher or just a cooker.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can define an ordering between instances of a Ruby class by doing the following two steps:

1. `include Comparable` in the class definition.
2. Define a method `<=>` that takes a single parameter, which is another instance of the class. This method should return 1 if the receiver (`self`) should be considered greater than the other object, -1 if it should be considered lesser, and 0 if they are equal.

This isn't ActiveRecord-specific but I see no reason why it shouldn't work for an ActiveRecord class.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to create a "group" attribute. So:

your head of school with be group => 1
your helpers would be group => 2
your teachers would be group => 3

Then, something like `Employee.order(:group).order(:last_name)` would order by your groups and then order by last_name.

to have a custom order, add that as your secondary sort.